# How to create consequative sequence of each date in a vector of length specified by another vector

Tags: r, date, sequence, repeat

```
dates <- "2018-07-14" "2018-04-19" "2019-08-15" "2018-12-04" "2018-05-02" "2019-04-14"
length< - c(2,4,3,5,1,3)
```

With a sequence by 1 I want to have a sequence for each date of the length to form

```
"2018-07-14" "2018-07-15" "2018-04-19" "2018-04-20" "2018-04-21" "2018-04-22" "2019-08-15" "2019-08-16" "2019-08-17" "2018-12-04" "2018-12-05" "2018-12-06" "2018-12-07" "2018-12-08" "2018-05-02" "2019-04-14" "2019-04-15" "2019-04-16"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the corresponding `vector`s with `Map`, use `seq` to get the sequence of 'date' `by` a day, while specifying the `length.out` as each of the values in 'length'

```
do.call(c, Map(function(x, y) seq(x, length.out = y, by = '1 day'), 
       as.Date(dates), length))
#[1] "2018-07-14" "2018-07-15" "2018-04-19" "2018-04-20" "2018-04-21" "2018-04-22" "2019-08-15" "2019-08-16" "2019-08-17" "2018-12-04"
#[11] "2018-12-05" "2018-12-06" "2018-12-07" "2018-12-08" "2018-05-02" "2019-04-14" "2019-04-15" "2019-04-16"
```

#### data

```
dates <- c( "2018-07-14", "2018-04-19", "2019-08-15" ,"2018-12-04", 
        "2018-05-02", "2019-04-14")
length<- c(2,4,3,5,1,3)
```

Comment: what does the x and y refer to?

Comment: @aaa..hhh it is a lambda function which is a function created on the fly.  Here the arguments 'x', 'y' signifies the 'date', 'length' individual elements as we are looping over them in `Map`

Comment: I keep getting the error 'length.out' must be of length 1

Comment: @aaa.hhh are you using the same data in my post?  It is working fine for me